# Is $\sqrt2$ a tricky notation?

Tags: soft-question

When someone asked me how to solve $x^2=9$,I can easily say, $x=3$ or $-3$. But what about $x^2=2$? There is NOT any "ordinary" number to solve this question. It's an irrational number. So we say helplessly, the answer is $\pm\sqrt2$, but what does $\sqrt2$ mean? It's a number, when squared, equals $2$.

This is a cycle define, just like "what's grandfather mean?father's father - what's father mean、grandfather‘s son." It does NOT tell anything more. And if we can define notations ‎arbitrarily, we can give any questions answer tricky. For example, what's $123456789\times987654321$? We need not calculate, just define $f(x)=123456789x$, the answer is $f(987654321)$.

Comment: Father = mothers partner! Aswell ;)

Comment: This is a good observation. You are right. We need to *prove* the existence of this number by some means. Typically, one argues that $f(x)=x^2-2$ is continuous, and applies the intermediate value property. This can be phrased in other ways, but ultimately is a consequence of the supremum (or completeness) axiom of the real numbers.

Comment: @Chinny84: What if the mother has been divorced and got a new partner? What if she is just... loose and has many partners? You can still have only one father.

Comment: @AsafKaragila you are totally right but I didn't want to add those cases..but the father must of been a partner of sorts (by sorts I wanted to keep it pg ;))

Comment: But more seriously, to the layperson, the sqrt is similar construct as the imaginary number? I don't know for sure.

Comment: I take it you won't be happy about the quintics so! The whole symmetry group of galois theory is cool, but it's implications are kind of saddening for a general quintic equation - http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_equation

Answer (score 4):

Very good, you understand what is going on here!

*It does NOT tell anything more*

Right, it is just a useful notation. Would you prefer to write

- $$
  \sqrt 2
  $$
- the unique number $\sigma \geq 0$ that has the property $\sigma^2=2$

every time you need that number in a computation? There is nothing more to the notation, it is a shortcut, that's all. The interesting world is somewhere else: In order to use such a notation, you have to prove that such a number **exists** and that it is **unique**.

And in order to do that you have to know a lot of things about the set $\mathbb R$: a very interesting story.

You may not believe it, but if a mathematician has to compute $123456789 \times x$ very often, he **will** define $f(x)=123456789x$, and his answer to the question: What is $123456789 \times 987654321$? will be:

*You mean $f(987654321)$? Do you want to know the digits?*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $\sqrt{2}$ only tells you that it is a number which, when squared, yields $2$. It's a whole lot more informative than any other thing you might write for the same number. However, the fact that $\sqrt{2}^2=2$ is really important in certain contexts. For instance, in higher mathematics, we are often less concerned with the easily determined fact $\sqrt{2}$ is somewhere between $1.4$ and $1.5$ than we are with other questions about it.

In particular, some branches of mathematics stop thinking about the real numbers altogether and stop thinking about arranging things on the number line, and just want to talk about addition and multiplication. They start off in the rational numbers, $\mathbb Q$, equipped with their ordinary addition and multiplication and move further. Quickly, one can create questions which have no solution, like:

> What $x$ satisfies $x^2=2$?

which can't be solved in the rationals. However, a very natural question is, *"Well, supposing there **were** a solution to that, what properties might it have?"* So, we define a new number, $\sqrt{2}$ and *extend* the rationals by it to the field $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$. What's this mean?

Well, now we're considering any number which can be written as a polynomial, with rational coefficients, of $\sqrt{2}$ - or equivalently, the numbers that can be written as a sum or product of rational numbers and $\sqrt{2}$. So, we're now interested in things like $\sqrt{2}+1$ and $\frac{1}2-3\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}^3$ and how addition and multiplication might work with them. Provably, every such number is of the form
$$a+b\sqrt{2}$$
for rational $a$ and $b$ and we define addition and multiplication as
$$(a_1+b_1\sqrt{2})(a_2+b_2\sqrt{2})=(a_1a_2+2b_1b_2)+(a_1b_2+b_1a_2)\sqrt{2}$$
$$(a_1+b_1\sqrt{2})+(a_2+b_2\sqrt{2})=(a_1+a_2)+(b_1+b_2)\sqrt{2}$$
which might not look like much at first, but suddenly, we have a new *field* in which we can perform addition and multiplication (and we even find results like division if we look harder) - and we find curious things like defining $\overline{a+b\sqrt{2}}=a-b\sqrt{2}$ preserves all the structure of multiplication and addition, which tells us that $\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$ are somehow interchangeable.

This branch of mathematics is too large to summarize in any adequate way, but essentially, my point is that the *algebraic* properties of a number - that is, how it responds to addition and multiplication - are very worthwhile in their own right, and hence, though the notation involves "inventing" new numbers that we can't write in any satisfying closed form like we can the rationals, the definition "$\sqrt{2}$ is a number which, when squared, gives $2$" actually has a lot of interest to it.